# A little puzzle with the way to compute the formula for Surface Integral of a Vectors Field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I have just found a website that explains how to construct the formula of Surface Integrals of Vectors Fields in an intuitive way (link [here](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/flux/flux.html)). However, there's a very confusing step, that is:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXZcs.png)

$$Volume = (\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert cosθ)dS = (\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert\left\lvert \vec n\right\rvert cosθ)dS = (\vec F \cdot \vec n)dS$$

$$Flux = \iint_S (\vec F \cdot \vec n)dS = \iint_S F(x,y,z) \cdot \langle -g_x (x,y), -g_y (x,y), 1\rangle dA $$

I don't understand why there is $\left\lvert n\right\rvert$ suddenly appearing in the formula above ?

To me, it should be as follows:

$$cosθ = \frac{\left( \vec F \cdot \vec n\right)}{\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert\left\lvert \vec n\right\rvert}$$

$$dS = \left\lvert \vec n\right\rvert dydx$$

$$Volume = (\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert cosθ)dS = (\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert\frac{\left( \vec F\cdot\vec n\right)}{\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert\left\lvert \vec n\right\rvert})\left\lvert \vec n\right\rvert dydx = \left( \vec F\cdot\vec n\right) dydx$$

$$Flux = \iint_S (\vec F\cdot\vec n) dydx = \iint_S F(x,y,z)\cdot\langle -g_x (x,y), -g_y (x,y), 1\rangle dydx $$

Is my way of thinking correct ?

Comment: Just an FYI, $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}$ is written as `\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n}` rather than `\vec{F} . \vec{n}`

Comment: Fixed. I'm not fluent at the codes for math symbols.

Comment: It's fine, we all have to learn somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

We have $|n|=1$, hence

$|F| \cos \theta = |F|\cdot|n|\cos \theta=F \cdot n$.

Comment: Is it OK if I substitute $$cosθ = \frac{\left( \vec F.\vec n\right)}{\left\lvert \vec F\right\rvert\left\lvert \vec n\right\rvert}$$ into the formula ?

Comment: Yes, it's alright to use this

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know why $(\left\lvert F\right\rvert\left\lvert n\right\rvert cosθ)dS = (F.n)dS$ ? $cosθ$ and the magnitude symbol of the two vectors suddenly disappear.

Comment: It is a property of the canonical scalar product : $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n, (a | b) = ||a||||b||\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Suppose that we have two vectors $a$ and $b$. The connection between the angle $ \theta$ between these vecors and their inner product $a \cdot b$ is: $a \cdot b=|a| \cdot |b| \cos \theta$ .

Comment: Dayum ! It is just the formula that I used above. Thanks Fred.

Answer (score 0):

When you write $dS = |\vec n|\,dx\,dy$, the $\vec n$ here is *not* the unit normal, whereas in the flux integral $\vec n$ is supposed to be the unit normal.

What's going on is this: Letting $\vec N = \langle -g_x,-g_y,1\rangle$ be the fundamental cross product, we do in fact have $dS = |\vec N|\,dx\,dy$. Then
$$\vec F\cdot\vec n\, dS = \vec F\cdot \underbrace{\left(\frac{\vec N}{|\vec N|}\right)}_{\vec n} \underbrace{|\vec N|\,dx\,dy}_{dS} = \vec F\cdot\vec N\,dx\,dy.$$